# Ansible 2.4 uri module downloads file (1K) even when it does not exist - url returns 404 error

Tags: ansible

I am trying to run the following code, looking for myfile.JAR file which does not exist at the given url. I am expecting this task to fail and not download any file.

```
    - name: Download using URI
      uri:
        url: "http://1.2.3.4:8081/myurl/myfile.JAR"
        dest: ./
        method: GET
        status_code: [200]
```

The task fails but yet under ./ there is a myfile.JAR of 1K size.

Why is it downloading this file (true size is 20MB)

Comment: Any reason you're not using `get_url` to download the file? `uri` is intended to interact with web services, whereby `get_url` is designed specifically for downloading files. It doesn't specifically answer the question of why this is happening, but it might fix your problem.

Comment: I am trying to evaluate which method behaves which way. I might even use maven_artifact which is more appropriate to download .JAR files from repositories. But wanted to know more about this uri module behaviour. Thank for your reply.

Comment: What you see in the downloaded file `myfile.JAR` is the html error message of the webserver. Works as described in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly modifying your playbook to

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:
  - name: Download using URI
    uri:
      url: "http://www/myurl/myfile.JAR"
      dest: ./uri.jar
    ignore_errors: yes
  - name: Download using GET_URL
    get_url:
      url: "http://www/myurl/myfile.JAR"
      dest: ./get_url.jar
    ignore_errors: yes
```

results to the following:

- `uri` downloads the file, i.e. the contents of the html error message of the webserver.
- `get_url` does not download anything that does not exist

Why?

`get_url` is especially for downloading the contents of the given url. If the http status code is not 200 then nothing is downloaded, that means if the file does not exist on the remote webserver the task only fails.

`uri` on the other hand is for interacting with webservices like REST or SOAP or what ever. When a restful request fails with a http status code of `400` for example additional information can be transmitted in the body of the response. For examples see https://praveer09.github.io/technology/2016/07/07/rest-error-responses-in-spring-boot/ And exactly this contents is downloaded with the `uri` task. The saved result can then be processed by further tasks.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense now. As you mentioned, get_url checks for code 200 OK and if it does not find the file then it does not download. I tried it before ... so basically I wanted to download the file but ignore the case since the repo has .jar or .JAR but could not try without looping or with_items.